# Delay() in CarbonCore/OSUtils.h deprecated in mac os x 10.8

Tags: objective-c, osx-mountain-lion, deprecated, macos-carbon

The CarbonCore/OSUtils.h has been deprecated in Mac OS X 10.8. I was using the `Delay()` from it. Now, I need to replace with Cocoa equivalent. I think `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:]` can be a replacement. Please suggest what would be the best replacement for the same. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am simply using Delay() for making half-a-second delay.

Comment: OTOH, blocking the current thread is an anti-pattern. For nearly every possible use of such functions, there is a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am simply using Delay() for making half-a-second delay.

The equivalent would be the `usleep` function, declared in `unistd.h`.

`Delay` suspends a thread. A run loop is not needed if you don't need to handle events on that thread in the meantime.